# Display loading progress image when Page Loads or does PostBack using ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I my project some times to loading a page it takes around 1 or more minutes so i want to show to user a wating message or wating status.

I my project i have a `login.aspx`page with tow buttons and `welcome.aspx`page and `clientsDatas.aspx`page and a `Master` page.

I don't found some ways to use JQuery like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}
$('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

i put that into my MasterPage and in the loading method of the other child pages i put :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=bt_submit]').click(); });";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
        }
```

but it dosn't work.

that is my CSS:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: black;
z-index: 99;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.loading {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
display: none;
position: fixed;
background-color: White;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Can i put only one code into my masterPage and it can be executed every time when a submit button of the child pages is clicked ?

Can any one help me?

Comment: do you want you to display loading message till your whole DOM get loaded?

Comment: I want to display a wating message when i click on a X and Y  button and not when i click on a Z button

Comment: Do not use `.live()` unless you can't use **jQuery 1.7+**

Comment: @Ishettyl what can i use rather tha .live() ?

Comment: Bind the handler once the appropriate element has been loaded into the DOM

Comment: @Basic how can i do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because i have a master Page and many child pages i added a part of Jquery code into the master form of my MasterPage and when the masterForm is submited (when submiting is so long it shows the wating image)

JQuery code whitch i added to my masterPage:

```
<%-- Start of wating message  --%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#MasterFormID").submit(function () {
            $("body").addClass("loading disp");
            $("#modal").addClass("disp");                
        });
    </script>
    <div id="modal" class="modal" style="text-align: center">
    </div>
    <%-- End of wating message  --%>
```

The style:

```
.modal {
display:    none;
position:   fixed;
z-index:    1000;
top:        0;
left:       0;
height:     100%;
width:      100%;
background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
            url('../images/ajax-loader-image.gif') 
            50% 50% 
            no-repeat;
}
.loading {
overflow: hidden;   
}
.disp {
display: block;
}
```

NB: i have to import JQuery into my masterPage.

So i did that and i worked good for me